# Link to a cell in a chart title in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a link to a cell in a chart title so that it is dynamic. The cell contains a formatted number (1 decimal place). In the chart title it appears with multiple decimal places.

Example:

```
="Year average:" & A4
```

In the cell (A4) it will show a number e.g. 82.3 but in the chart title it appears as 82.2651431

Does anyone know how I can change this?

Comment: Please upload the excel file so we can take a better look. Also I think you can set it to a certain numbers after the decimal but I'm not sure since I don't have the excel file.

Comment: Can't see a way to upload a sample of the file. It is sensitive information

Comment: Maybe you could recreate the problem in a different excel file with no sensitive information. and then upload that one instead.

Comment: Don't know how to upload the file to this site - can't see a link

Comment: Upload it to a site like Megaupload or dropbox. and post the link

Comment: @RamonRobben: in general questions should be self containing with screenshots and sample data, sharing files is not preferred, please don't request for it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász ah okay. the question wasn't really clear to me thats why I requested a file so I could see what he meant but I won't anymore. Thanks telling me.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [TEXT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function.  Your cell's formula would be something like:

`="Year average:" & text(A4,"0.0")`

Format your number to taste-the formatting variable will accept any [Excel Custom Formatting](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm) values (except color, I think).

Comment: Yeah, it won't get the color in a custom number format.